# Определить тип объекта

Tags: javascript, typescript

Есть массив данных состоящий из объектов:

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Интерфейс для объектов в массиве:

```
export interface IDepList{
    count_versions: number
    created_at: string
    current_version: string | null
    id: number
    name: string
    short_description: string | null
    slug: string | null
    total_weight_of_version_files: number
    type: string
    updated_at: string

}
```

Не могу сообразить, каким образом я могу правильно определить тип этого массива?

В моем представлении должно работать `Array<IDepList>`, но получаю ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: нужно просто заменить `object` на `IDepList`

Comment: @Grundy я нигде не использую object

Comment: Тогда так https://techformist.com/interfaces-arrays-typescript/

Comment: Используешь :-) в том месте где получаешь ошибку.

Answer (score 0):

Так попробуйте

```
interface IDepList{
    [index: string]:IDep
}


interface IDep{
    count_versions: number
    created_at: string
    current_version: string | null
    id: number
    name: string
    short_description: string | null
    slug: string | null
    total_weight_of_version_files: number
    type: string
    updated_at: string

}

let depList = new Array<IDep>();
```

Comment: Получаю ту же ошибку.

Comment: Приложите код где вы используете.